# Redux - Identical reducers, containers, and components are producing different results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

**edit: Solution was hooking up a different variable to the mapStateToProps.**

I'm having some trouble with my react-redux application and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

The source code can be [found here](https://bitbucket.org/DigitalMockingbird/redux-checkbox-sandbox/src).

The `Alphabetical` action and reducer seem to the working correctly, but unlike the `Duplicate` logic, the glossary doesn't rerender when the Alphabetical buttons are toggled. I'm guessing this is because I haven't hooked it into the store / dispatch correctly.

I created the `Duplicate` reducer, action, containers, components, and once I got those working, I copied the code to the `Alphabetical` files. Aside from the variable names, the code should be identical, but when I run each reducer individually in the createStore, `duplicates` is working correctly and `alphabetical` is not.

You can see how the `Alphabetical` buttons should behave by using `toggleDuplicates` in the createStore function (I'm still figuring out why combining the reducers isn't working - maybe this is related to the problem?).

**src/entry.jsx**

Change allReducers to `toggleDuplicates` or `toggleAlphabetical`

```
let store = createStore(
    allReducers,
    initialState,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(createLogger())
    )
);
```

To run, cd into the directory, then run `npm install`, `npm run server`

The intended behavior is the `Duplicate` and `Alphabetize` buttons will update the GlossaryTable with the correct values when toggled. The `GlossaryTable` should be rerendered when the `visibleWords` state is updated (after being returned by the toggleDuplicates / toggleAlphabetical reducers.

**src/containers/GlossaryContainer.js**

This is where I think I may not correctly be wiring up the state to the dispatch.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  visibleWords: getVisibleEntries(
      state.words,
      state.visibleWords,
      state.toggleDuplicates,
      state.toggleAlphabetical
  )
});

const VisibleGlossary = connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(GlossaryTable);

export default VisibleGlossary;
```

Comment: Avoid the initialState when you create the store, just pass it in your reducers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a reducer called `words` that's not actually a reducer but an array.

`words` should just be data in your store, not a reducer itself